# How treat a point where a function is not defined for indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a question maybe stupid but I don't know how solve it.

Solving the indefinite integral I have a doubt:

When I have a definite integral usually we check if  the interval of integration is finite or if the function to be integrated is well defined, in the interval of integration, if not I am talking of a improper integral.
For example $\int_0^x \frac{1}{x}$ is an improper integral since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$.

$\textbf{My question:}$ when I have an indefinite integral, for instance $\int \frac{1}{x} dx$, and for $x=0$ the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined, in particular $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$, I have to take into account this fact or not? How can I treat $x=0$ in this case?

Comment: An indefinite integral $\int f(x) \, dx$ is nothing but an anti-derivative, i.e. a function $F$ with $F' = f$. If $f$ is not defined at $x_0$ then $F$ is not defined at $x_0$ either.

Comment: Ok thanks and so since $\int \frac{1}{x}=\log{|x|}+c$ as matter of fact $\log{|x|}$ is not defined in $0$ right?

Comment: Yes, $F(x) = \log |x| + c$ is defined on $\Bbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, differentiable on that set, with $F'(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!

Comment: And actually $c$ can have different values for $x>0$ and $x<0$ (if you want the most general antiderivative).

Answer (score 4):

The indefinite integral $\int f(x) \, dx$ is just a notation for the antiderivative, i.e. a function $F$ with $F' = f$. This implies that the domain of $F$ is a subset of the domain of $f$.

Your example function $f(x) = 1/x$ is defined on $\Bbb R\setminus \{ 0 \}$, therefore an antiderivative can only be defined on that set.

The notation $\int f(x) \, dx = F(x) + C$ is sometimes used to indicate that the “general antiderivative” is obtained by adding an arbitrary constant to $C$, e.g.
$$
\int \frac 1 x \, dx = \log |x| + C \, .
$$
As Hans Lundmark said, care must be taken if the domain of $f$ consists of multiple components. Strictly speaking, the general antiderivative of $1/x$ is
$$
 F(x) = \begin{cases}
  \log (-x) + C_1 & \text{ for } x < 0 \\
  \log (x) + C_2 & \text{ for } x > 0 \\
 \end{cases}
$$
with real constants $C_1, C_2$.

Back to your original question: If $f$ is not defined at a point $x_0$ then there is no antiderivative at $x_0$. **But:**

- If the domain of $f$ consists of multiple intervals then the constant of integration can be independently chosen on each interval on which the antiderivative exists.
- The [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) in the form $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a)$ is only valid on each *interval* on which the antiderivative exists.

  As an example, it would be **wrong** to say that $\int_{-1}^1 \frac 1x \, dx = \log|1| - \log |-1| = 0$.

Comment: This needs to come with a huge warning that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus does __not__ apply to a domain where a point is missing. So if you pick two specific values of $C_1$ and $C_2$ (say both $0$) and try to say that $\int_{-1}^1 = F(1) - F(-1)$, you will be wrong.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: Good point, thank you.

Comment: Glad to see you added it your answer! I've seen that specific example as a math puzzler so often that my comment was made in anticipation of it. :-)